# Migrate chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3: How to update these APIs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I want to migrate a Chrome manifest v2 extension to v3 and thus need to update several API calls.

Google's instruction on how to migrate to v3 [lists](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#sunset-deprecated-apis) at the bottom a bunch of deprecated APIs, however the guide ends there and doesn't mention or link a reference that lays out which deprecated API was replaced by which new API. I haven't found info on this anywhere else either - any ideas?

For example one of the listed APIs is `chrome.extension.getURL()`, which is used a lot by my extension.  But I couldn't find how to update it so that I am able to migrate to v3.

Comment: This is an ancient alias of chrome.runtime.getURL, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here the new Chrome extension API for manifest v3:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
chrome.extension.onRequest => chrome.runtime.onMessage
chrome.extension.onRequestExternal => chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal
chrome.extension.lastError => chrome.runtime.lastError
chrome.extension.getURL() => chrome.runtime.getURL()
chrome.extension.getExtensionTabs() => chrome.extension.getViews()
chrome.tabs.Tab.selected => chrome.tabs.query({active: true})
chrome.tabs.sendRequest() => chrome.runtime.runtime.sendMessage()
chrome.tabs.getSelected() => chrome.tabs.query({active: true})
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow() => chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true})
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged => chrome.tabs.onActivated()
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged => chrome.tabs.onActivated()
chrome.tabs.onHighlightChanged => chrome.tabs.onHighlighted
```

As well as the undocumented:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
chrome.extension.connect() => chrome.runtime.connect()
chrome.extension.onConnect => chrome.runtime.onConnect
chrome.extension.onMessage => chrome.runtime.onMessage
```

Comment: Thanks, i got `chrome.runtime.getUrl() is not a function`.
seems like the correct one is `chrome.runtime.getURL` https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL

Comment: A file name must be inside. An example is this:  img.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('logo.png');